# Get project ID without using training module on custom vision?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the Custom Vision API and the sample I found out on github / docs included the training and creation of a project. However, I have done the training and creation part online (http://customvision.ai).

Now in order to predict the image, I need project ID.

```
endpoint.PredictImage(project.Id, testImage);
```

Where can I get this one from?

*I am only interested in using the Prediction API without having to train from my code.*

Your thoughts please.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to get the project url from the website is to open the project in a browser and look at the URL; the project id is the GUID listed after /projects: `customvision.ai/projects/<ProjectID>#/manage`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can call `TrainingApi.GetProjects()` to retrieve a list of ProjectModel objects, and get the project id you need by checking its properties (like `Name` or `Description`).

Comment: This requires pulling in the training API package though. There is no way to get the ID using just the prediction API.

Comment: Yes, I figured!